# Can we use CAST function while writing a foreign key in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

I tried doing this but failed.

```
ALTER table emp ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Dept  
FOREIGN KEY (dept) REFERENCES dept (CAST (deptid) as INT)
```

I got into this situation because, `Deptid` in emp table is char and int in dept table

Comment: if possible then Change `Deptid` in `emp ` table to `int` otherwise no need to use foreign_key relationship, you can't use it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this. The data types has to match between the keys involved in the constraint. The proper action would be to correct the data type in the `emp table`.

If the data in the `dept` column of the `emp` table is integers stored as chars and matches the data in the `dept` table (which it would have to for the constraint to work at all), you should be able to alter the table to change the type and then add the constraint like this:

```
alter table emp alter column dept int;
alter table emp add constraint FK_Dept foreign key (dept) references dept (deptid);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

I think you should think about:
- retyping the column or 
- inserting the converted value in a column

You cannot do it neither with Views, because you cannot reference to them!

Hope to help you